# SimpleXMLElement Object showing instead of default key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm attempting to build an array for CSV export and can't figure out why my array is building a sub array with just a string.

Any help would be appreciated.

PHP:

```
foreach($Entry as $list){
  $pushArray = array($list['firstEntry'], $list['secondEntry']);
  array_push($csv, $pushArray);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($csv);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title1
            [1] => Title2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 1.1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 2
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 2.1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 3
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Test Entry 3.1
                )

        )

)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title1
            [1] => Title2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test Entry 1
            [1] => Test Entry 1.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test Entry 2
            [1] => Test Entry 2.1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test Entry 3
            [1] => Test Entry 3.1
        )    
)
```

Comment: what method did you use for $csv?

Comment: What do you mean? it's an array

Comment: I mean how you showed the csv that now it is  SimpleXMLElement Object one method is reading the file or fgetcsv and seperate it what you did use print_r($csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pushArray = array((string) $list['firstEntry'], (string) $list['secondEntry']);
```

You've to cast SimpleXML elements to string type if you're using it that way